# How can Randomize the cases in switch condition without repeating

Tags: android, random, switch-statement

Hi I am trying to make an Android App in this model.Main aim is to Randomize the cases in the switch condition Shown in the below code. As I am Again calling the method in each case, The chances of appearing the same images is high.So , I wanna know how can I make this Logic to show images in order (I.e., I want to randomize, but the image once appeared should not appear until all the Image cycle is completed)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

//int blue,green,yellow,red,brown,white,pink,black;
//Boolean BLUE,GREEN,YELLOW,RED,BROWN,WHITE,PINK,BLACK;
ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3,fs;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    iv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
    iv3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);
    fs = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_fs);
    fs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    switchingLogic();

}

public void switchingLogic() {      
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.nextInt(4)+1;

    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.touch_blue);
        mp.start();
        iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_blue_1);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_blue_2);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_blue_3);
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switchCases();

                iv_gone();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.correct_cheers);
                mp.start();

                fs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fs.setImageResource(R.drawable.big_play_blue);

            }
        });
        iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        iv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        break;

    case 2:
        iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_green_1);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_green_2);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_green_3);

        iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switchCases();
                iv_gone();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.correct_cheers);
                mp.start();
                fs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fs.setImageResource(R.drawable.big_play_green);
            }
        });
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        iv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        break;
    case 3:
        iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_yellow_1);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_yellow_2);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_yellow_3);

        iv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switchCases();
                iv_gone();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.correct_cheers);
                mp.start();
                fs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fs.setImageResource(R.drawable.big_play_yellow);
            }
        });
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        break;
    case 4:
        iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_red_1);
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_red_2);
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_red_3);

        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switchCases();
                iv_gone();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.correct_cheers);
                mp.start();
                fs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fs.setImageResource(R.drawable.big_play_red);
            }
        });
        iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        iv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
      }
    protected void switchCases() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                fs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                switchingLogic();
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
    public void iv_gone() {
        iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Is there any solution or Any alternative is available. Thank You.

Comment: Well firstly, I would suggest you to use only 1 Random object, a single random will gives you more even result. Second, I see that you are calling nextInt(8) + 1, which I assume you are expecting 1 ~ 8? but you only catching case 1 ~ 4, why is that? Third, maintain an List<Integer> object, everytime you call for a random, save the result in it, so next time, check whether your result is contained in the List, if contained, recall your random function, until the list size reached the maximum, 4 I believe? Then clear the List.

Comment: Yeah Maximum Image size is 4 only, previously I used 8 & forgot to change that. Any how Same response will be there.

Comment: Put the Static Random random = new Random(); as member variable.

Comment: @Chor WaiChun: "Well firstly, I would suggest you to use only 1 Random object, a single random will gives you more even result. " . How? as I am using only one Random Object & calling it every time the Image is correct. Actually I didn't get that first point , will you please elaborate.

Comment: Well, just have a List saving your recent results, recall switchLogic if your new results is already in List until you get a new 1, save your new new result into the list. So whenever your list is full with 4 different integers, clear the list. It should works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of my comment, try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    //int blue,green,yellow,red,brown,white,pink,black;
    //Boolean BLUE,GREEN,YELLOW,RED,BROWN,WHITE,PINK,BLACK;
    ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3,fs;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Random random = new Random(); // Use only one random object, do not redeclare it
    List<Integer> recentResults; // A list saving your results

    public void switchingLogic() {      
        if(recentResults == null) recentResults = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(recentResults.size() == 4) recentResults.clear();

        int x = random.nextInt(4)+1;

        while(recentResults.contains(x)){
            x = random.nextInt(4)+1;
        }

        recentResults.add(x);

        switch (x) { 
            case 1: {
                // Other codes
                setSpecialOnClickListenerWithDrawable(iv1, R.drawable.big_play_blue);
                setGeneralOnClickListener(iv2);
                setGeneralOnClickListener(iv3);

                break;
            }
            // Other cases here
        }
    }

    public void setGeneralOnClickListener(ImageView iv) {      
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // v here will refers back to iv itself
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setSpecialOnClickListenerWithDrawable(ImageView iv, final int drawable) {      
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switchCases();

                iv_gone();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.correct_cheers);
                mp.start();

                fs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fs.setImageResource(drawable);
            }
        });
    }

    // Your other codes here
}
```

Well I made a simple application performing above and I get a x results of: 4 3 2 1 2 4 1 3 3 1 4 2 1 3 4 2 3 4 2 1. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for reply...   "recentResults.add(x);" ----> here it is showing: "The method add(int, R.integer) in the type List<R.integer> is not applicable for the arguments (int)" . Do you have any Idea Plz Chor....

Comment: Check how you declared List<Integer>, make sure cases are correct, and the Integer is a class of java.lang.Integer

Comment: Exactly,got it . Just a minute , I'l integrate with my code & let you know the result.

Comment: Yes !!! got it , Its working (Images are not repeating continuously, but simultaneously)May be this can Satisfy my BOSS.Thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind can you explain What is happening here:   "while(recentResults.contains(x)){
            x = random.nextInt(4)+1;
        }

        recentResults.add(x);
"

Comment: On the recentResults.add(x) you can see we always keep track of what result we have shown earlier. So, `while(recentResults.contains(x))` will return true, if x, is shown before, and if it is true, we renew the x value, until recentResults.contains(x) returns false. Returning false means this x has not been displayed recently. So when this list is full of all 4 types of results, we refresh the list by clearing it.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot for explanation. Now I got it. By looking at my app, what you conclude. Is it a better approach to meet my requirement. Say, if I want to extend my app to have to display some 32 images in next version. So, should I create all the 32 cases (Or) is there any better approach to reduce the code .Please....

Comment: having 32 cases shouldn't be a problem, but I see you have a lot of repeating codes like setvisibility and some iv.setonclicklistener, I believe you can sumarize them into a function, while having only different codes in switch cases. Performance wise I do not see any problem.

Comment: Oh I forgot to ask, How can I put iv.setOnClickListener() in a function.  AS I have to show three iv's on a view.And only one of them contains the correct image to be shown fullscreen & the rest two iv's were set to disappear onClick Of them. Like that I have 4 cases at present & will increase further according to the requirement. Is it possible to sum them up in a function(or method).If yes , then HOW?  Please Can you explain me.

Comment: Well I'll edit this answer for better readability, can't do much on comments.